# `decltype` of generalized lambda capture inside body of a lambda - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, language-lawyer, shadowing

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    auto l = [k = 0]
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(k), int>);
    };
}
```

- `clang++` (10.x and trunk) happily compiles the code above.
- `g++` (10.x and trunk) fails to compile the code above with the following error:

  > ```
  > error: static assertion failed
  >    10 |         static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(k), int>);
  >       |                       ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  > ```

  Apparently, `g++` believes that `decltype(k)` evaluates to `const int`.

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/azWPdx)

Since the type of the data member `k` should be deduced from `0` (which is a plain, non-`const`, `int`), I think that this is a `g++` bug. In my mental model, the only thing that is `const` is the `operator()` of the lambda, but not the synthesized data member `k`.

- **Is my assessment correct?**
- **What does the standard say?**

Comment: if it helps, clang compiles `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), Foo>);` and gcc compiles `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), const Foo>);` so I dont think its an issue with `int i;`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the language only requires that `k` shall not be modified. I'd guess that implementing this by making the synthesized member `const` (as gcc appears to be doing), is allowed, and so both are right.

Comment: @cigien [Not so sure about that](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-6). For the most part, the standard goes to great pains to treat the occurrences of variables inside a lambda body as actually "directly" referring to the things in the enclosing scope, not to the members of the closure type. Apparently it does the same for initializing captures.

Comment: [gcc seems a bit confused on what the type of `k` actually is lol. It's `int` on one line, `const int` on the next.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dzozcr).

Answer (score 8):

The standard is rather explicit in this case. [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#6):

> An *init-capture* without ellipsis behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “`auto init-capture ;`” whose declarative region is the *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement*, [...]

so your code is (roughly - see the rest of the quote above to see how the two differ) equivalent to the following, which [gcc accepts!](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mn3dEx):

```
auto k = 0;
auto l = [k]
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(k), int>);
};
```

So who's right? For that we see that the type of the `k`, which is `int` since `auto` deduces to `int` for `0`.

Then it is only a matter of looking at [[dcl.type.decltype]/1.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.3) which says:

> [...] if `E` [*the expression inside `decltype`*] is an unparenthesized *id-expression* [...], `decltype(E)` is the type of the entity named by `E`.

The type of the entity `k` is `int`. So gcc is wrong.